# What is /dev/kvm device in kvm virtualization?

Tags: device, kvm

What is /dev/kvm device in kvm ? I searched on google, but could not find any article on it. Can someone who is familiar with it, point me to any helpful resources ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the official documentation for it as part of the Linux kernel source code under `Documentation/virt/kvm/api.rst`

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/virt/kvm/api.rst